# Data annotation regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

How would one go about writing a data annotation regex for the following?

- Only digits and periods allowed
- Format: Block.Block.Block.Block (There must be 4 blocks and 3 periods at all times)
- Each block can contain up to 4 digits (1 digit at minimum)
- First block cannot start with a 0
- If any other block starts with a 0, then no digit can follow

Valid strings:

```
12.3.4567.0
1.1456.0.8321
4.1200.10.5
```

P.S. I'm not a Regex guru, and I don't know if the above is doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^[1-9]\d{0,3}(\.(0|[1-9]\d{0,3})){3}$`

See here for an annotated explanation of how it works :) http://regex101.com/r/gS4eL0

Comment: 1.1.1..1 does not match!

Comment: OK, I wrapped it with ^ and $. It looks great!